# Fetch data from api and store it in data class

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I'm quite new to development.
I know how to fetch from simple api's and store the data in kotlin data class something like this:

```
data class Property(
   val id: String, 
@Json(name = "img_src") val imgSrcUrl: String,
   val type: String,
   val price: Double
)
```

But how can i fetch and store data sturctue like this?

```
{
  "Thailand": [
    {
      "date": "2020-1-22",
      "confirmed": 2,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-23",
      "confirmed": 3,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: That is a `Map<String, List<Something>>`, where `Something` could be a `data class` holding your `date`, `confirmed, `deaths`, and `recovered` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare suggested in the comments, I was able to get the data like this:

```
    fun getPropeties():
            Call<Map<String, List<Property>>>
}
```